# Search filter on two fields based upon condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

Here is my table

```
create table Table1 (Id int, ...some fields... , CategoryId int, ProfileId int)
```

I want to write a SP(stored procedure) which will give me search results from the table based upon the parameters passed to the SP. Here is my procedure

```
Create proc Search
(
  @MediaType1 varchar(1000),
  @MediaType2 varchar(1000),
  @MediaType3 varchar(1000)
)

as

begin

  select * from table
  where 
  case when @MediaType1 = '' then 1 else CategoryId end in 
    (select case when @MediaType1 = '' then 1 else Splvalue end 
        from dbo.Split(case @MediaType1 when '0,' then '1,2,3,4' when '' then '1,' else @MediaType1 end,','))
    and
    case when @MediaType2 = '' then 1 else ProfileId end in
    (select case when @MediaType2 = '' then 1 else Splvalue end 
        from dbo.Split(case @MediaType2 when '0,' then '2,12,13' when '' then '1,' else @MediaType2 end,','))
    and
    case when @MediaType3 = '' then 1 else ProfileId end in 
    (select case when @MediaType3 = '' then 1 else Splvalue end 
        from dbo.Split(case @MediaType3 when '0,' then '1,14,15,16' when '' then '1,' else @MediaType3 end,','))

end
```

Basically, what I want to achieve is when '0' is passed in @MediaType1 variable, it should return all records which have category (1,2,3,4) else it should only that category which is passed (e.g. 3) else if its blank, it should show all records. Same way for @MediaType2 and @MediaType3 except that they should check for ProfileId. The condition is also that all three or two or one of the parameters could be blank, I need to handle those and show the filtered records.

My above query works only if one parameter is passed and rest all are blank. I also tried

```
where
(@MediaType1 <> '' and Category in (select Splvalue from dbo.Split(@MediaType1,',')))
or
(@MediaType2 <> '' and ProfileId in (select Splvalue from dbo.Split(@MediaType2 ,',')))
or
(@MediaType3 <> '' and ProfileId in (select Splvalue from dbo.Split(@MediaType3 ,',')))
```

but even this does not works. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wrote the SP like this and it worked

```
Create proc Search
(
  @MediaType1 varchar(1000),
  @MediaType2 varchar(1000),
  @MediaType3 varchar(1000)
)

as

begin

  if (@MediaType1 = '' and @MediaType2 = '' and @MediaType3 = '')
  begin 
    set @MediaType1 = '0,';
    set @MediaType2 =  '0,';
    set @MediaType3 =  '0,';
  end 

  select * from table
  where 
  ((@MediaType1 = '0,' and CategoryId in (1,2,3,4)) or (CategoryId in (select Splvalue from dbo.Split(@MediaType1,','))))
    or
    ((@MediaType2 = '0,' and ProfileId in (2,12,13)) or (ProfileId in (select Splvalue from dbo.Split(@MediaType2 ,','))))
    or
    ((@MediaType3 = '0,' and ProfileId in (1,14,15,16)) or (ProfileId in (select Splvalue from dbo.Split(@MediaType3 ,','))))

end
```

Answer (score 0):

If I just rewrite what you said as conditions:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE 
 (@MediaType1 = '' OR (@MediaType1 = 0 AND CategoryId IN (1,2,3,4)) 
  OR @MediaType1 = CategoryId)
 AND
  (@MediaType2 = '' OR (@MediaType2 = 0 AND ProfileId IN (1,2,3,4)) 
   OR @MediaType2 = ProfileId )
 AND
  (@MediaType3 = '' OR (@MediaType3 = 0 AND ProfileId IN (1,2,3,4)) 
   OR @MediaType3 = ProfileId )
```

Comment: Sorry mate, that worked for individual parameters but not for multiple, I passed 4 in MediaType1, it gave me category 4 records, I  passed 16 in MediaType3 it gave me 16, but when I passed both, it gave me blank

Comment: Do you want to do it with OR instead of AND for each mediaType? Updated the answer.

Comment: well the OR just opened up everything, now filters are not working, everything is visible every-time

Comment: So what exactly should happen if you pass 4 to MediaType1 and 16 to MediaType3 ?

Comment: It should show all records who have CategoryId = 4 as well as also those records who have Profileid = 16

Comment: So how come OR does not do that? Are you passing '' to @MediaType2?

Comment: dont know buddy, even I am confused

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60540/discussion-between-bulat-and-hitesh-salian).